# Angular 6- pagination not working with data-table

Tags: datatable, pagination, angular6

I am requesting data from the server and able to display it in data table successfully .For some reason i had to use "table mat-table" instead of "mat-table" in html after this the pagination functionality stopped working. It was working fine earlier when i was using "mat-table" element .
Also, the reason for using "table" tag was to dynamically hide the columns with no data which i was not able to do earlier. If there's a work around for this ,please let me know .
Thanks in advance!

```
public array: any = [];//declaring an empty array

import { MatTableDataSource, MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material';
import {MatPaginator,  MatSort} from '@angular/material';
constructor(private router: Router, private Auth: AuthService ) { }

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);

  displayedColumns: string[] = this.array;//passing array to displayedColumns

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 }

getRecords(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const target = event.target;



this.someService.getDetails()
 .subscribe(
   data =>{

     this.Response=data.data,
     this.dataSource.data = this.Response,
     console.log("fetched data :",this.Response);
     for (var item of Object.keys(this.Response[0])){
      this.array.push(item);// PUSHING THE FETCHED COLUMNS TO ARRAY
    }
   }
 );this.resetArray();

 }
```

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-paginator #paginator
    [length]="dataSource.data.length"
    [pageIndex]="0"
    [pageSize]="50"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
</mat-paginator>
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>User Id</mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element">{{element.userId}}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element">{{element.title}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element">{{element.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="completed">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Completed</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element">{{element.completed}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="blank">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Blank</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef= "let element"></mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" style="background-color:#bcd8f1;border-color: red;"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
 </mat-table>

</div>
```

Data table shows the records with dynamic columns and pagination works fine ,but instead of showing new data only, the data table columns are appended with prevoiously loaded columns and then gets displayed.

Comment: can you create and add a stackblitz?

Comment: i found out what is wrong but i can't find the solution for it...the problem is i am initializing my data source as - "dataSource = this.Response;"  instead of "dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Response);" I searched and found out that paginator only works with MatTableDataSource . But i want to use it like this  "dataSource = this.Response;"  only. Is there a way i can apply pagination using this only?

Comment: I don't think so, unles you want `this.Response` to implement abstract class DataSource

Comment: can you provide me some source explaining how to display only the columns that contain data using MatTableDataSource then?

Comment: You can always build your table to display dynamic colums, there are some examples from the angular team already

Comment: okay..i'll check it out ..thank you:)

Comment: i just found out a workaround for my problem..but now i am facing another issue...in order to get dynamic columns in matDatatableDataSource i parsed the response object and fetched the columns in an array and passed that array to "displayedColumns" so that only those columns get displayed which are fetched.

Comment: now the new issue is that the array which i am passing to the displayed columns is not getting empty...instead if i get some other columns from the API ,they get appended to the array and columns from prevois request and current request gets displayed....if i initialize the array to null after passing to displayed columns ..null gets passed to the displayedColumns and nothing is shown in the data table....i am updating my code..please take a look at it!

Comment: please create a stackbliz, it will be easier to help with somes codes

Comment: okay..ill try creating a stackblitz using a dummy api.

Comment: I am getting this error in stackblitz : Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js (21647:27)
No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'. What do i do to resolve this?

Comment: I will suggest you fork an existing google stackblizt and add the code you need

Comment: here ..i got it working..."https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-data-table". Now, if click submit button...the data will be loaded perfectly...but if you click that button again..the array values get appended to the previous ones...check the console for this!

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `stackblizt`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  /*
    These variables are not needed
  */
  // public data: any = [];  
  // public array: any = [];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  // View child require 2 PARAMS
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private service: Service) { }


  ngOnInit() { 
    this.loadData();
  }

  showTable() {
    // I dont know what you really want to do here.
    if(this.dataSource.data.length === 0){
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  loadData() {
    this.service.getAuthRecords1().subscribe(
      data => {
          this.dataSource.data = data as any,
          console.log("dummy data :", data);
        if (this.displayedColumns.length === 0){
          this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(data[0]);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: tried your code...it's not working. It shows the data correctly the first time..but if i call the service again which will return different columns this time without refreshing the page ,the console.log shows that  the array values remains the same..hence data-table shows previous data only.

Comment: i guess,when i call the service second time that returns different columns, the array already contains values from the previous request ,hence it does not enter the loop .

Comment: i got it working...in the else loop, i first initialised the array to null and then passed the columns to it. Thanks a lot @Morlo for helping me out...i appreciate it :))